# Deleting Tablib Dataset Column Headers skipping unexpectedly in Django Import Export

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I have a `csv` file with this sample data:

[image]

in which I am trying to modify `django-import-export`'s `before_import` function and overwrite the dataset, and in order to do so I need to empty the current dataset and replace it with a new one. Here is how I do it:

```
def before_import(self, dataset, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
    """
    code to create a new_dataset
    """

    print(dataset.headers)
    # delete data rows in dataset
    del dataset[0:len(dataset)]
    # delete headers
    for header in dataset.headers:
        del dataset[header]

    print(dataset)

    """
    code to replace dataset with the new_dataset
    """
```

what the shown code does is delete the dataset's data and its headers. But the print shows not all headers are deleted.

[image]

It skips headers being deleted, or more accurately, it alternates in deleting them.

Is there something I'm missing in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It causes some kind of memory error when you delete the contents of an array inside a FOR LOOP that also uses that array as the reference for the for loop.

For good measure, copy the array first:

```
import copy
...
reference_array = copy.copy(dataset.headers)
```

Then use this as the reference for your for loop deletion

```
for header in reference_array:
     del dataset[header]
```